# Sharepoint WSS 3.0 2007: Automatic workflow not starting most of the time

Tags: 2007, workflow

Running exactly version 12.0.0.6535. I have created a couple workflows to help the automate vacation approval process. When a new item is added to a list, the workflow should start and send an email out for somebody to approve it. However, the workflow doesn't always get initiated.

Another issue is that I don't have direct control over our server because an external company hosts it. If I manually start the workflow it will run fine.

This process needs to be flawless though. Can't have vacation days waiting to be approved forever.